# Creating a DF in R by selecting rows based on greatest local value in one column

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have some soil data from gSSURGO listed with profiles with each profile containing horizons at successive depths. So basically,

```
> chorizon <- read.csv("chorizonexcel.csv", header = T)
> 
> chorizon [1:10,1:8]
   OBJECTID hzname desgndisc desgnmaste desgnmas_1 desgnvert hzdept_l hzdept_r
1         1      A         0          A       <NA>         0        0        0
2         2     Bk         0          B       <NA>         0        0       18
3         3   2BCk         2         BC       <NA>         0        0       64
4         4      A         0          A       <NA>         0        0        0
5         5     Bk         0          B       <NA>         0        0        8
6         6   Bkkm         0          B       <NA>         0        0       18
7         7    CBk         0         CB       <NA>         0        0       71
8         8      A         0          A       <NA>         0        0        0
9         9     Bk         0          B       <NA>         0        0        6
10       10   Bkkm         0          B       <NA>         0        0       21
```

Lowest profile depths in `chorizon$hzdept_r` are always the largest and always come before the 0 top depth of the next horizon. (Profile 1 depths: 0, 18, 64; Profile 2 depths: 0, 8, 18, 71; etc.)

I am trying to get:

```
OBJECTID hzname desgndisc desgnmaste desgnmas_1 desgnvert hzdept_l hzdept_r
3         3   2BCk         2         BC       <NA>         0        0       64
7         7    CBk         0         CB       <NA>         0        0       71
10       10   Bkkm         0          B       <NA>         0        0       21
```

I have been attempting to generate a loop to create a new df of only the lowest horizons.

If this has been answered already, I haven't found it for the last 6 hours. I apologize if this is too basic a question.

Comment: So by "lowest" you mean "largest"?

Comment: Largest value aka lowest horizon. I need to "select row i if column value in row i is >= column value of row i+1 or row i-1" and place those rows in a new df.

Comment: searc SO for `[R] selecting dataframe value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options:

```
chorDT[c(tail(hzdept_r==0, -1), TRUE)]
chorDT[c(diff(hzdept_r) < 0), TRUE)]
etc..
```

Here is a full solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
chorDT <- data.table(chorizon)

chorDT[c(tail(hzdept_r==0, -1), TRUE)]

   OBJECTID hzname desgndisc desgnmaste desgnmas_1 desgnvert hzdept_l hzdept_r
1:        3   2BCk         2         BC       <NA>         0        0       64
2:        7    CBk         0         CB       <NA>         0        0       71
3:       10   Bkkm         0          B       <NA>         0        0       21
```

Comment: This correctly included the profiles with only one horizon at 0 top depth. Thank you for this invaluable tool package.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = chorizon$hzdept_r
n = length(x)
pts = which(diff(x)<0)
if(x[n]>x[n-1]) pts = c(pts,n)
chorizon[pts,]
```

Comment: `R` has a `diff` function for `x[-1] - x[-n]`   Try the following:       `identical(x[-1] - x[-n] <0,  diff(x) < 0)`   .